# In debugging, how to know the stats (max-min, average, distribution...) of an argument in a repetitive calls to a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Supposed I have a function `void Myclass::func(x)`, and various other code make thousands of calls to it. Now I want to know some stats of the argument `x`, for example, the average, max, min, or even a distribution graph.

```
void Myclass::func(int x) {
    while(foo.doFancyStuff(x)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's some ad-hoc methods that come to my mind:

1. Print each value of `x` to log. Then use external tools/scripts to analyze them.

   - Caveats: Mixed with other info in logs. Writing each value of `x` into external log or file on filesystem is slow.
2. Define global variable to store them and analyze at the end of execution of interest.

   - Caveats: Global variables are bad. They will get confusing in the future.
3. Store them in class `Myclass`.

   - Caveats: Not reusable code. What about next time I want to analyze `Otherclass::doOtherStuff(y)` ? And bad integration, because that stats code should not be coupled with the `Myclass` itself.

Is there any tool/library to do this? I'm using Visual Studio on Windows, so would like an answer usable for this platform. Cross-platform tools are welcome, too.

Comment: Why do you want this? Can you give a real-world example? Btw "Slow." Well, you have to give out some time to do this, no?

Comment: You could use the python API of `lldb` to automatically call a function each time a breakpoint is hit and collect the frame info there to process it.

Comment: @L.F. I was referring to excess time of writing each value into external log or a file on filesystem. Edited.

Comment: @lubgr Thanks I will look into it. Though I was more looking for solution to be used with VS on Windows. Tag added.

Comment: @oldherl If I were you, I would try to change the code as little as possible, cuz too much debugging code mixed into normal code creates great confusion for me (and the future maintainers of the code.) But this would require an extraordinary debugger equipped with super-power... (not really)

Comment: @L.F. I would surround my debug code with `#ifdef DEBUG` as much as possible, to avoid both confusion and efficiency lost.

Comment: code with lots of `#ifdef DEBUG` is imho both confusing and inefficient to read :P

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using the scripting API of `lldb` (which works on Windows, too). Take this trivial program,

```
void func(int x) {}

int main(int, char **)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        func(i);
}
```

which you can analyze with such a script

```
import lldb
import os

fArgs = []

def analyzeFrame(frame, bpLocation, dict):
    variables = frame.GetVariables(True, False, False, False)
    x = variables.GetValueAtIndex(0).GetValueAsSigned()
    fArgs.append(x)
    return False

debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
debugger.SetAsync(False)
target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch("pathToYourExecutable", "")

bp = target.BreakpointCreateByName("func", 4, lldb.SBFileSpecList(), lldb.SBFileSpecList())

bp.SetScriptCallbackFunction("analyzeFrame")

process = target.Launch(target.GetDebugger().GetListener(), [], [],
    None, None, None, os.getcwd(), 0, False, lldb.SBError())

print("max: {}".format(max(fArgs)))
print("min: {}".format(min(fArgs)))
```

You need to make sure the python interpreter finds the `lldb` module. The path can be seen by executing `lldb -P` on the command line.

Comment: My code will be compiled by Visual Studio, not llvm or clang. Does lldb still work with that?

Comment: `lldb` should work with arbitrary executable binary regardless of the compiler used.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no single simple answer. What you want is a variation of instrumentation debugging, which means that someone needs to inject additional code in your class to handle this case.

For a portable way, the only option you have is to add a cache of the previous values, then in your class destructor, output the statistics that you want. The way you cache data is up to you, you can design a simple `Stats<>` class, member of the class that you want to monitor and make calls to it to store new values. That would be what I would try first, as it's portable, almost clean and reusable.